# NPM Frontend Proxy Set, but Can't Download NPM Package

Tags: node.js, jenkins, proxy

We are using the [Eirslett Maven Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to help build our NPM projects in a standard way. This frontend takes care of installation and other issues for us. Plus, it allows our developers to build via `mvn package` just like they do with with our other Java/Maven projects.

This builds on my local machine with a proxy warning, but it won't build on our Jenkins server.

I have `$HOME/.npmrc` configured and both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables set. Yet, I still get a no proxy is set error.

```
$ set | grep "http.?_proxy"
http_proxy=http://proxy.xxxx.local:3128
https_proxy=https://proxy.xxxx.local:3128

$ cat $HOME/.npmrc
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy = http://proxy.xxxx.local:3128/
https-proxy = https://proxy.xxxx.local:3128/
strict = false
ca = null


$ mvn clean package
[...]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.24:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ ihcm-config-tool ---
[INFO] Installing node version v0.12.2
[INFO] Creating temporary directory /opt/tomcat/jenkins_home/jobs/ihcm-config-tool-trunk/workspace/node_tmp
[INFO] Downloading Node.js from \\  
       http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.2/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64.tar.gz \\  
       to /opt/tomcat/jenkins_home/jobs/ihcm-config-tool-trunk/workspace/node_tmp/node.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.968 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-18T11:53:39-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal \  
        com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.24:install-node-and-npm \  
(install node and npm) on project ihcm-config-tool: Could not \   
download Node.js: Could not download \  
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.2/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64.tar.gz: \  
Connect to nodejs.org:80 [nodejs.org/104.20.23.46, \
nodejs.org/104.20.22.46] failed: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

I can download http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.2/node-v0.12.2-linux-x64.tar.gz to my machine. I think the error may be the proxy, but I could be wrong. Anything I should be looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the problem.

The Eirslett Maven Frontend Plugin does not use `$http_proxy` or the proxy settings in the `$HOME/.npmrc` file. Instead, I had to put the proxy setting inside my `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` file.

I created a special version of my `settings.xml` file with the added proxy settings (just to make sure that nothing is going to affect other projects). I created `$HOME/.m2/settings.proxy.xml` and then called Maven via `mvn -s $HOME/.m2/settings.proxy.xml`.

We use Artifactory which has its own proxy settings. We have configured *NPM* to use our Artifactory server for downloading. However, the Eirslett Maven Frontend Plugin can also install *NodeJS* too and Artifactory can't be set as the *HOME* of NodeJS.

We want the Eirslett Maven Frontend Plugin to install *NodeJS* if it's not already installed. This way, a new developer can get this project to build with just running `mvn package` much like they do with all of our other projects. Fortunately, the proxy isn't needed for the developers' machines. However, our Jenkins server is behind a corporate inner firewall and needs the proxy setup.

Comment: Could you please share the settings.proxy.xml file that you created with the npm proxies , as I am facing the same issue .